# SQL injection in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-injection

Is my code safe and secure ?

```
if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) 
    con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand();
cmd4.Connection = con;
cmd4.CommandText = "exec [Insert_Request] @FileCode = " + FileCodeArchiveID + ", @FirstName = '" + FirstName_RequestInsert_textBox.Text + "' ";
cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open) 
     con.Close();
```

Or is it better to use `cmd4.Parameters.Add()` ?

Comment: Definitely not safe. You really should read up on what SQL injection is because you would have been able to answer this question yourself.

Comment: It's not safe. You are inserting user input unsanitized into your query. Always use parameterized queries for that.

Comment: You could use `cmd4.CommandType = StoredProcedure`, `cmd4.CommandText = "[Insert_Request]"` and use SqlParameters to fill the parameters without hard coding it in the query call.

Comment: For avoid SQL injection you should write stored procedure: cmd4.CommandText = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Comment: Stored procedures aren't necessary, just parameters instead of string concatenation.

Comment: Also, look into sanitizing the data (i.e. text inputs) before it makes it your data layer/SQL commands.  Along with malicious SQL, you also don't want to store valid client side scripts that could expose your UI and users.

Comment: No, don't mangle user input. You want 1 part data validation (reject what you don't want, save what you do) and 1 part output encoding (e.g. `<` should be converted to `&lt;` so the browser outputs "<" instead of parsing tags). Imagine if SO removed script tags from code examples; so many questions and answers would not appear as they were intended because that part of the text was not saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, avoid using string concatenation when building SQL commands/queries. Especially if one or more segments are coming from an untrusted source, like user input.

You should do something like so:

```
     SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand();
     cmd4.Connection = con;
     cmd4.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cmd4.CommandText = "Insert_Request";
     cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileCode", FileCodeArchiveID);
     cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName",FirstName_RequestInsert_textBox.Text); 
     cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

For once, It's easier to read (in my opinion), and secondly using parameters sidesteps the sql injection vulnerability.

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Is there a reason we shouldn’t be using it?

Comment: That's what the link is for.

Comment: check the parameter values fror escape characters and SQL commands as well not that they'd get in but why play nice with some one who is trying. also make sure you're database connection it self is encrypted als any one can read the data from the network